Table of contents formatting in MS Word
Word no longer displays outline level 3 in the table of contents (I, II, III ...). The headings are still displayed, but without outline level. Two days ago, however, it was still correct (see comparison). I have already deleted the table of contents and reinserted it, checked the list levels.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please attach a link to a sample document that has the problem. Here is my article on how to do this. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258 - Your sample should include both some of the relevant headings and the Table of Contents.
